# How to make TypeScript automatically update callback parameter to the return type of optional function in interface?

Tags: typescript

Assuming there is a Column interface, `render` and `dataFormat` are optional:

```
interface A { ... }

const c1: Column<A> = {
  render(data) {
    // data: A
  }
}

const c2: Column<A> = {
  dataFormat(rawData) {
    // rawData: A
    return { a: 1 }
  },
  render(formatedData) {
    // formatedData: { a: number }, equal to return type of dataFormat
  }
}
```

I've tried many ways, but none of them worked. So how to declare the Column interface?

Answer (score 0):

you will need a no-op helper function to do this:

```
function createColumn<Input, FormatOutput = Input>(c: Column<Input, FormatOutput>) {
  return c
}

interface Column<Input, FormatOutput = Input> {
  dataFormat?: (raw: Input) => FormatOutput,
  render?: (formatedData: FormatOutput) => any
}

const c1 = createColumn({
  render(data: A) {
    // ...
  }
})

const c2 = createColumn({
  dataFormat(rawData: A) {
    return { a: 1 }
  },
  render(formatedData) {
    // ...
  }
})
```

note that you have to annotate `A` in `render` or `dataFormat` because there is two generic parameter so you can't only assign one (eg. `createColumn<A>(...)`)